# Is it useful to train arms in circuit, 10 reps?

Tags: bodybuilding, arms

I'm short in time, during my pull work-out.

I only have approx. 15min, max.20 to train my arms. The exercises I'd want to do are: supination curl, dumbells bird (post. delt.), neutral curl, pronation curl.

If I do 1 set of the first exercize, then 1 set of the second, then of the third, then of the fourth, then the 2nd set of the first exercize, etc. at 10 reps each, **without any pause** ,  would it be useful to hypertrophy my arms (and increase will it increase my support grip)?

Is it possible for the triceps too?

Comment: You can definitely do workouts in a circuit but what you're proposing is: biceps, delta, biceps, biceps. I don't think a circuit will help much here. It might if you worked in different muscles to the circuit. Are you open to that?

Comment: These circuits are part of larger work-out for upper body :) I need a circuit training because of lack of time. But I'd want to be sure that these circuit trainings are useful for hypertrophy and grip endurance

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely work your arms and save time by doing a circuit or by performing super-setting. However, I don't believe doing back-to-back bicep workouts will help you.

The idea behind super-setting is that you work different muscle groups. While one muscle group is being worked, the other muscle group rests. You lose this benefit when you just do the same muscle. I think it would negatively impact your hypertrophy since the muscle is exhausted. You would work closer to failure but I believe you'd need to drop the weight to meet any rep criteria.

Instead, I would do your workout using super-sets. The first workout pair is A (so you do A1 set 1, then A2 set 1, then A1 set 2, etc.), and then you'd go to group B. You called this your *pull* workout day, so something like:

> **A1:** Pull-ups
> **A2:** *Supinated bicep curls*
>
> **B1:** Barbell rows
> **B2:** *Neutral bicep curl*
>
> **C1:** Deadlift
> **C2:** *Pronation curl*

In this fashion you're combining a back workout with a bicep workout. Your biceps will get a short "rest" while you're doing the other workouts.

Personally, it would be even better if you just did an arm workout without focusing on just the *pull* part. That way you could do the following, as an example, and it would be closer to the circuit you might have in mind:

> **A1:** *Tricep*
> **A2:** *Bicep*
> **A3:** *Delt*
>
> **B1:** *Bicep*
> **B2:** *Tricep*
> **B3:** *Forearm*